# How can I return multiple objects in a function in php and then display them

Tags: php

```
public function getdata()
{
    $ctrObj =  new Country();
    $result = $ctrObj->ctrydata($this->table);
    if(mysqli_num_rows($result)>0){
        while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) {
            return $row;
        }
    }
}
```

```
$ctryObj = new CountryController();
$countries = $ctryObj->getdata();
print_r($countries);
```

when I `print_r($countries);` then I can see only one object but if I print that in function mentioned above I found all objects.

Comment: return an array of rows

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can yield it :

```
public function getdata()
{
    $ctrObj =  new Country();
    $result = $ctrObj->ctrydata($this->table);
    if(mysqli_num_rows($result)>0){
        while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) {
            yield $row;
        }
    }
}
```

You would use it like this (with a lot of benefits for memory...) :

```
$ctryObj = new CountryController();
foreach ($ctryObj->getdata() as $country) {
    print_r($country);
}
```

Edit : I've learned with PDO and never been in contact with mysqli so I've tried to find an equivalent to fetchAll(), and apparently, you have a fetch all function also (http://php.net/manual/fr/mysqli-result.fetch-all.php).

I think your code would look like that :

```
public function getdata()
{
    $ctrObj =  new Country();
    $result = $ctrObj->ctrydata($this->table);
    if (mysqli_num_rows($result) > 0) {
        $rows = mysqli_fetch_all($result);

        return $rows;
    }
}
```

This looks more efficient that getting all your objects one by one to bind them into an array (as it's done by php natively). Anyway, use `yield` if you don't want to duplicate the buffer of results (one for mysql side, the other one for php side)

Answer (score 3):

You could save results in an array and return it:

```
public function getdata()
{
    $data = []; // Init array
    $ctrObj =  new Country();
    $result = $ctrObj->ctrydata($this->table);
    if(mysqli_num_rows($result)>0){
        while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) {
            $data[] = $row; // Populate it
        }
    }
    return $data; // Return it
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Because you return only one result, you can change like this

```
public function getdata()
    {
    $ctrObj =  new Country();
    $result = $ctrObj->ctrydata($this->table);
    $rows = [];
    if(mysqli_num_rows($result)>0){
        while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) {
             $rows[] = $row;
         }
     }
    return $rows;
   }
```